# Laravel 4.2 Carbon\Carbon class not found

Tags: php, laravel, autoload, php-carbon

I'm reinstalling a Laravel site due to a server mishap and running into an issue with Carbon class not being found. I have the site running on my local machine and it works fine, but when installing onto the server I get the following:

```
[2015-07-12 21:40:54] staging.ERROR: exception 
  'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 
  'Class 'Carbon\Carbon' not found' in 
   /data/webs/stage.mysite.org/bootstrap/compiled.php:7883
```

I deleted the vendor and bootstrap/compiled and installed using composer again. Also tried composer update. The only difference between my local and remote I can determine is the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php on my local has the Carbon\Carbon class listed. The remote does not. All my autoload classmaps and psr-4 from composer.json are there also. It seems the only thing not loading is Carbon.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: The Carbon he means is a php dateTime library @halfer. http://carbon.nesbot.com

Comment: Have you tried to re-generate the compiled.php file? `php artisan optimize --force`. You should only need the `--force` option if your sit is set to debug mode.

Comment: Is carbon present in the vendor folder? Make sure your composer.json on the server is up to date

Comment: @Brett - No, nesbot directory was there but nothing in it. For some reason, it was not being installed during the Laravel installation. They only way I solved it was copying a local version I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesbot/carbon directory was in the vendor directory but had nothing in it. Which tells me something was wrong during install, no matter how many times I tried it. There were never any errors messages though.

It's not really an answer, as I never figured out why, but I solved it by copying a local version of nesbot/carbon to the server.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to get free rep :D